# How to make hyperlinks clickable in Bluefish text editor to open the URL in a web browser?

Tags: browser, text-editors, url, hyperlink, bluefish

In the [Bluefish text editor](https://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html), how does one make hyperlinks (URLs) clickable so they open the URL in a web browser?

I've looked through all of the application's options, and skimmed the manual, and I'm just not seeing how to accomplish this seemingly simple task.